# In beach volleyball what happens when a player hits the ball from under the net?

Tags: volleyball, beach-volleyball

To map this out, players A and B are on team 1, player C is on team two. Player A bumps the ball over the net to team two's side. Player B reaches underneath the net and (otherwise legally) hits the ball at player C.

Is this a legal play and should player C continue the volley?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fault by team 1 and they lose the point; it is covered by [rule 13.2.1 of the official FIVB rules](https://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB-BeachVolleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v05.pdf):

> 13.2 Faults of the attack hit
>
> 13.2.1 A player hits the ball within the playing space of the opposing team.

For what it's worth, there is nothing beach specific about this - exactly the same rule exists for indoor volleyball (except that it is numbered 13.3.1).